# Utilizar viewbags para metadados ou coloca-los em um ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

No cenário abaixo, possuo uma `View` que depende de algumas `ViewBags` para preencher `options` em `selects` `html`. Ao realizar o `POST` e caso algo dê errado no cadastro, o usuário é redirecionado para a mesma `View` com os campos preenchidos. Neste método `POST`, atualmente, estou replicando a criação das `ViewBags`. Esta é a melhor abordagem? É correto colocar a lista de meta dados (Estados, cidades, bairros, países) no `ViewModel` e carregar os `selects` por ele?

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar()
{
       ViewBag.Estados =[...]; //List de selectListItem
       ViewBag.Cidades = [...];
       ViewBag.Bairros = [...];
       ViewBag.Paises = [...];

       return View();
}

[HttpPost
public ActionResult Cadastrar(CadastrarUsuarioViewModel model)
{
       ViewBag.Estados =[...]; //List de selectListItem
       ViewBag.Cidades = [...];
       ViewBag.Bairros = [...];
       ViewBag.Paises = [...];
       try
       {
           //DoSomething
           ExibirMensagemSucesso();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }catch (Exception ex)
       {
            //Do Something
            return View(model);
       }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta ordem de instruções aqui não está boa:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(CadastrarUsuarioViewModel model)
{
       ViewBag.Estados =[...]; //List de selectListItem
       ViewBag.Cidades = [...];
       ViewBag.Bairros = [...];
       ViewBag.Paises = [...];
       try
       {
           //DoSomething
           ExibirMensagemSucesso();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }catch (Exception ex)
       {
            //Do Something
            return View(model);
       }       
}
```

Primeiro, que a captura de exceções deve ser feita no evento [`OnException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception(v=vs.118).aspx) do *Controller*, não na *Action*.

Segundo, que a carga dos itens deve ser feita **depois** da regra principal de negócios de uma *Action* decorada com `[HttpPost]`, não antes. Isto simplesmente porque, se a regra funcionar, você não vai devolver a mesma *View* de novo, então não tem porque carregar as *ViewBags* novamente.

Terceiro, que você não valida o *ViewModel*. Isto é feito pelo [`ModelState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) através da propriedade [`IsValid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid(v=vs.118).aspx). Há alta chance de a aplicação executar lógica não desejada aí.

Altere para o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(CadastrarUsuarioViewModel model)
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid) 
       {
           //DoSomething
           ExibirMensagemSucesso();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }

       ViewBag.Estados =[...]; //List de selectListItem
       ViewBag.Cidades = [...];
       ViewBag.Bairros = [...];
       ViewBag.Paises = [...];
       return View();
}
```

No mais, está ok.