# Pra que servem as variáveis model e Model em uma View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor, view

Pra que servem as variáveis `@model` e `Model` em uma *view*?

Na minha *view* eu uso assim no início do código:

```
@using Html5DataList.Models
@model List<Estabelecimento>
```

E pra acessar os dados, eu uso assim:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option value="@item.unidadeId">@item.cnes - @item.nomeFanta</option>
}
```

Meu *controller* está assim:

```
public ActionResult BPAC()
{
    List<Estabelecimento> listaEstabelecimento = new Estabelecimento().listaEstabelecimento();
    return View(listaEstabelecimento);
}
```

Funciona corretamente, mas eu uso apenas porque já vi assim, na verdade ainda não sei o que significam.

E, caso eu queira enviar mais de uma informação? Ex:

```
public ActionResult BPAC()
{
    string teste = "teste";
    List<Estabelecimento> listaEstabelecimento = new Estabelecimento().listaEstabelecimento();
    return View(listaEstabelecimento, teste);
}
```

Nesse caso, como eu recebo as variáveis `listaEstabelecimento` e `teste`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estão relacionados, onde `@model` define o tipo de `Model`, no seu código você definiu a `List<Estabelecimento>` e utilizou `Model` para acessar as posições dessa ***lista de estabelecimento***. Vale lembrar que a diretiva `@model` foi introduzido na versão `ASP MVC Beta 3`, [sendo que por essa diretiva define o tipo forte da View no `Razor`](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2011/02/13/asp-net-mvc-3-conhecendo-a-view-engine-razor/).

No caso de ter mais de um tipo, é criada uma `ViewModel` contendo esses dois tipos, da seguinte maneira:

## Exemplo

***Classe ViewModel***

```
public class EnvioParaView 
{
    public string Teste {get;set;}
    public List<Estabelecimento> ListaEstabelecimento {get;set;}
}
```

***Controller***

```
public ActionResult BPAC()
{
    EnvioParaView model = new EnvioParaView ();
    model.Teste = "teste";
    model.ListaEstabelecimento  = new Estabelecimento()
                         .listaEstabelecimento();
    return View(model);
}
```

***View***

```
@using Html5DataList.Models
@model EnvioParaView 


@foreach (var item in Model.ListaEstabelecimento)
{
    <option value="@item.unidadeId">@item.cnes - @item.nomeFanta</option>
}


@Model.Teste
```

ou seja, a variável `Model` foi definida em `@model` do tipo `EnvioParaView`. Dentro desse objeto tem duas informações a `List<Estabelecimento>` e o valor `string` `Teste`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [ASP.Net MVC – View Model Pattern – Quando e como utilizar?](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/)
- [View Model pattern and AutoMapper in ASP.NET MVC Applications](https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications)
- [How we do MVC – View models](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/)
- [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns](http://stevemichelotti.com/aspnet-mvc-view-model-patterns/)
- [How to use more than two models in MVC razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280246/how-to-use-more-than-two-models-in-mvc-razor-view)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3: New @model keyword in Razor](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor)
- [Introducing “Razor” – a new view engine for ASP.NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3: Conhecendo a View Engine Razor](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2011/02/13/asp-net-mvc-3-conhecendo-a-view-engine-razor/)

Answer (score 3):

@model é uma diretiva do Razor, o mecanismo de gabaritos que forma a página na *view*. Ele é usado para "tipar" o modelo.

A variável `Model` está vinculada a esta declaração, é ela que usará para acessar o dado que vem da chamada da *view*, provavelmente pelo *controller*. É algo implícito.

É possível declarar outros dados na própria *view* de outras formas, o que não faria muito sentido, salvo em casos bem simples e específicos, afinal deve fazer o mínimo necessário na *view* que não seja a apresentação.

A título de curiosidade o seu exemplo está criando uma classe assim:

```
public class _Views_Account_Login_cshtml : RazorPage<List<Estabelecimento>>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/RazorPage.cs).

então a variável `Model` será do tipo `List<Estabelecimento>` que bate com o que está sendo enviado em `View(listaEstabelecimento)`.

Quando acessa `Model` na verdade está acessando a classe `_Views_Account_Login_cshtml`, tudo sem que você veja.

Se quiser enviar mais de uma informação tem que criar um outro modelo especificamente para a *view* consumir, geralmente através de uma classe que chamamos de *viewmodel* (pode saber mais sobre esta forma em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101)). Já tem algumas perguntas mostrando como fazr isso em ASP.NET MVC:

- [Como usar vários models em uma view](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99808/101)
- [Como enviar 2 objetos do Controller para a View no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91021/101)
- [Boas práticas com .NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41411/101)
- [Como funciona o ViewModel no asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130770/101)
- [Utilizar viewbags para metadados ou coloca-los em um ViewModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62555/101)